# Error in marker pose estimation using single camera

Tags: opencv, camera, geometry, markers, pose-estimation

I use the following OpenCV code to estimate the pose of a square Marker and draw the 3 axises of the marker on the image. But the Z-axis of the marker rotates 180 degrees time to time as shown in the image below. How to make the z-axis stable?

```
// Marker world coordinates
vector<Point3f> objecPoints;
objecPoints.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));
objecPoints.push_back(Point3f(0, 2.4, 0));
objecPoints.push_back(Point3f(2.4, 2.4, 0));
objecPoints.push_back(Point3f(2.4, 0.0, 0));

// 2D image coordinates of 4 marker corners. They are arranged in the same order for each frame
vector<Point2f> marker2DPoints;

// Calculate Rotation and Translation
cv::Mat Rvec;
cv::Mat_<float> Tvec;
cv::Mat raux, taux;
cv::solvePnP(objecPoints, marker2DPoints, camMatrix, distCoeff, raux, taux);

// Draw marker pose on the image
vector<Point3f> axisPoints3D;
axisPoints3D.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));
axisPoints3D.push_back(Point3f(2.4, 0, 0));
axisPoints3D.push_back(Point3f(0, 2.4, 0));
axisPoints3D.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 2.4));

vector<Point2f> axisPoints2D;

// Take the camMatrix and distCoeff from camera calibration results
projectPoints(axisPoints3D, Rvec, Tvec, camMatrix, distCoeff, axisPoints2D);

line(srcImg, axisPoints2D[0], axisPoints2D[1], CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
line(srcImg, axisPoints2D[0], axisPoints2D[2], CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1, CV_AA);
line(srcImg, axisPoints2D[0], axisPoints2D[3], CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, CV_AA);
```

[image: Pose estimation results at time t]
[image: Pose estimation results at time t+1]

Comment: It looks to me that the right marker (ID 4) is symmetrical (if you flipped it over an axis, it would still register as the same Aruco marker). If that's the case, it appears that the orientation of the tag is ambiguous. Does this only happen for ID 4? (ID 3 is not symmetrical; I wonder if you could switch out ID 4 for a similarly non-symmetrical tag).

Answer (score 0):

This probably would be better as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that. I think this may be happening due to the order in which solvePnP is getting the coordinates for your tag. <del>Furthermore, since solvePnP is just trying to match (in this case) 4 points on a 3D plane to 4 2D points in an image, there are multiple solutions for this. The tag could be rotated around its up axis, as well as flipped upside down. solvePnP doesn't know from the provided points which is the upwards facing direction.</del>

<del>I have a hunch that solvePnP is a bit too general for this problem as stable tag detection algorithm should be able to feed the corners to the pose estimation code in a stable order.</del>

Edit: order of the corners is important and the solution given by solvePnP depends on it. Perhaps the algorithm generating your corner points is not providing the corners in a consistent order? Please share the output of tags.points

Comment: I found this in the [source of the latest OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/src/aruco.cpp#L843) where internally they are also using solvePnP to estimate the pose of a new tag called ArUco.

Comment: Four corners of the markers are already ordered correctly and consistent for all the frames. Corner points are marked with different color dots (green, blue, black & cyan) and they are consistent as shown in the top and bottom images.